# Fetch Array display

Tags: php, arrays

So i got this for display in row my sql select:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT nome_sitio, horario, contato, morada, imagem FROM sitio where id_tipo=1");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Nome</th>
<th>Horário</th>
<th>Contato</th>
<th>Morada</th>
<th>Imagem</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['nome_sitio'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['horario'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['contato'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['morada'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['imagem'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
```

But i made a design in html, that with html and css looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gb1s9.png

And the html code is:

```
<div id="sitios">
<div class="imageRow">
<div class="single">
<a href="backoffice/images_sitios/$imagem" rel="lightbox"><img src="backoffice/images_sitios/thumbnails/$imagem"/></a>
</div>
</div>
<div id="texto">
<h2><b>$nome_sitio</b></h2>
<h3><b>Morada:</b></h3> $morada</br>
<h3><b>Horário:</b></h3> $horario</br>
<h3><b>Contato:</b></h3> $contato</br>
<h3><b>Freguesia:</b></h3> $idfreguesia

</div>
</div>
```

Can someone help me replacing the text with the vars?

Comment: Can you do <pre>print_r($result)</pre> and post the results here

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape back to PHP to display the variables:

```
<div id="sitios">
<div class="imageRow">
<div class="single">
<a href="backoffice/images_sitios/<?php echo $imagem; ?>" rel="lightbox"><img src="backoffice/images_sitios/thumbnails/<?php echo $imagem; ?>"/></a>
</div>
</div>
<div id="texto">
<h2><b><?php echo $nome_sitio; ?></b></h2>
<h3><b>Morada:</b></h3> <?php echo $morada; ?></br>
<h3><b>Horário:</b></h3> <?php echo $horario; ?></br>
<h3><b>Contato:</b></h3> <?php echo $contato; ?></br>
<h3><b>Freguesia:</b></h3> <?php echo $idfreguesia; ?>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i put that code here: while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "yourcode";

and its not working ..

Comment: If you use `echo` then you don't need the `<?php` escapes, your original code should work. But you need to set all the variables from `$row`, e.g. `$nome_sitio = $row['nome_sitio'];`

Comment: what is the best way to display the select i made to the db and format the result with that design?

i just want to see all my "places", like this:http://i.stack.imgur.com/gb1s9.png

im not being able to do it

Comment: Use the first code you wrote in your question, just change things like `<td>` to `<h3><b>`. I don't understand why this is a problem.

Comment: yes i know. but the " and ' screw everything. can you help me right this in an echo? <a href="backoffice/images_sitios/$image" rel="lightbox"><img src="backoffice/images_sitios/thumbnails/$imagem"/></a>

Comment: i got it working! just a question te query select the id_freguesia that is a foreign key on the table, how can i do to go get the freguesia name from the freguesias table instead of display the id of it?

Comment: Use a JOIN, of course. That's a basic SQL technique, if you don't understand then you need to review your SQL tutorials.